# How to use multiple Azure App Configurations in one client application

Tags: azure, enterprise, azure-app-configuration

Lets say we have 2 azure application configurations (TeamConfig and CommonConfig) and one client application (ClientApp).

**Case 1:**
Can ClientApp use both TeamConfig and CommonConfig at the same time?

**Case 2:**
Can TeamConfig link directly to CommonConfig?

**Side note:**
I have seen the possibility that TeamConfig can import from CommonConfig. But, what I am looking for is a dynamic link and not a import. When CommonConfig is updated it is automatically updated all the way down to the ClientApp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For case 1, yes.

For case 2, no.

In your application, you can load configuration from multiple App Configuration stores. For example,

```cs
configBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration("Connection string of CommonConfig");
configBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration("Connection string of TeamConfig");
```

In this sample, what's in TeamConfig will overwrite what's in CommonConfig if there are overlapping keys.